How do I temporarily pause / stop the Semantic Focus in Flutter programatically?
I am aware of this FocusSemanticEvent and I have used the clearSemantics()
But I don't want to clear the focus instead I would like to pause/stop the whole semantic focus in system level.
Is there any possibility for that?
